# Is there a word to describe the positioning of words directly below other words, as in translations

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I was hoping to use a word to say that in a song lyric, the translation of the original language appears directly below the original language throughout the song, without having to say all that.  I thought "subscribed" made sense (sub=below; scribed=written), but can't find any dictionaries that give that definition to the word.

Comment: Because human language is a **combinatoric art rather than a crossword puzzle**, we normally do and should use multiple words to describe elaborate concepts.

Answer (score 9):

According to dictionary.reference.com, [*interlinear*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interlinear?s=t) is:

> 1. situated or inserted between lines, as of the lines of print in a book: *a Latin text with interlinear translation.*

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is [*subtitling*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subtitling?r=66), which according to dictionary.reference.com is:

> 3.
>   Movies, Television.
>
> a.
>   the text of dialogue, speeches, operas, etc., translated into another language and projected on the lower part of the screen.
>
> b.
>   (in silent motion pictures) a title or caption.

Answer (score 0):

Juxtaposition is not very specific to music but could work.

According to Google, the word means:

> the fact of two things being seen or placed close together